# Notepad++ upload to FTP and keep file

Tags: web, notepad++

So I have a domain and a directory on my computer that can be accessed with my ipadress as link and I want so when I click save it uploads the updated version to the FTP AND updates the file on my computer so both my domain website and my ipadress website will be updated with the new changes, is that possible?

I'm sorry if it is hard to understand the text, kinda hard to explain to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Win-scp](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php).

Install it, then either:

- Open the file directly from the server and when you save the file will be uploaded
- click on [Keep remote directory up to date](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date) and once you save for file locally, winscp will upload it for you.

To work with Notepad++ with winscp you need to [configure winscp to use notepad++](http://elementdesignllc.com/2009/09/notepad-ftp-winscp/).